# How to get a vector iterator to point to a vector after vector.push_back() has caused reallocation?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a function `void AddEntity(Entity* addtolist)` that pushes elements back onto a `vector` but since the size and capacity are equal when the element is added to the `vector`, the vector reallocates and the `iterator` becomes invalid.

Then when I try to increment the iterator I get a crash because of the invalid iterator, since `push_back(...)` doesn't return a iterator to the reallocated memory I was wondering how to get around this problem.

Should I just use `insert(...)` since it does return an `iterator`, or should I use a pointer that stores the reference to the vector after its reallocated and then have the `iterator` equal the pointer that points to the reallocated `vector`?

Comment: Since you're using a vector, you could just use an integer or a size_t to keep track of the index yourself!

Comment: Why would you use previous iterator even after `push_back`?

Comment: @leetNightshade - I'm glad someone other than myself is recommending `size_t` for once but in this case the correct type would be `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

Comment: `insert` returns an iterator to the inserted element. `push_back` does not, because it is pretty obvious where the new element is!

Comment: @Chris Lutz - Ohh ok, thanks!  Yeah, I only mentioned int because some people seem keen on using it, but I tend to stick to size_t, so I can prevent errors and take advantage of the 64bit platform, or further take advantage of others like 128bit etc.  So, thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vector::push_back(const T& x);
```

Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. The content of this new element is initialized to a copy of x.

This effectively increases the vector `size` by one, which causes a reallocation of the internal allocated storage if the vector size was equal to the vector capacity before the call. ***Reallocations invalidate all previously obtained iterators, references and pointers.***

Using an invalidated vector is going to lead you to crashes or undefined behaviors.
So just get a new iterator by using `vector::begin()`.

```
vector<int> myvector;

vector<int>::iterator it;
it=myvector.begin()
```

Comment: @Als hmm, I've tried this before and it still seems invalid and crashes

Comment: @Just a humble programmer: It will not crash If you are obtaining a fresh iterator **after** the reallocation after **push_back**.

Comment: @Als the Iterator I'm using is part of a class that handles the list and updates the elements stored in the vector. How am I to go about obtaining a fresh iterator if the current one is part a class? Should I make a temporary iterator and have the old iterator point to the new one?

Comment: @Just a humble programmer: Forget about the old iterator after reallocations period! Can't you just assign the iterator you already have with `myvector.begin()` after the `push_back()`.

Comment: @Als that how I've always had it, even in the function that updates the individual elements of the vector first sets the Iterator to the beginning of the list, yet the program crashes with "Vector iterator not incrementable" runtime error and I assumed because the iterator is invalid then it can't be incremented

Comment: @Als I've been messing around with the debugger and found that another function was causing the iterator to reset to the beginning of the list midway through incrementing through the list. Thank you anyway, I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As @Als already answered, `push_back()` may invalidate all iterators if relocation takes place.

Dependent on the problem you try solve, `std::list` may be what you need. Adding element to `list` doesn't invalidate existing iterators to the container.